# Why in order to get the smallest number of bits we must use the log of probability of occurrence

Tags: machine-learning, entropy, cross-entropy

I was reading [this article](https://rdipietro.github.io/friendly-intro-to-cross-entropy-loss/) on Cross-Entropy. When talking about encoding elements of a distribution in order to minimise the number of bits, it says this:

*It turns out that if you have access to the underlying distribution $y$ , then to use the smallest number of bits on average, you should assign $\log\frac{1}{y_i}$ bits to the  $i$-th symbol.*

Why $\log\frac{1}{y_i}$?

How can we prove that this is the minimum?

Answer (score 1):

Lending from MacKay:

Let $x \in \mathcal{X}$ be a random variable that can take any outcome $a_i \in \mathcal{A}$. The *shannon information* of it's content is then given by

$$h(x = a_{i}) = log_2 \frac{1}{p_i}$$

where $p_i$ is the probability of the outome $a_i$, i.e. $p(x = a_i)$. Similarly the entropy of $\mathcal{X}$ is given by

$$H(\mathcal{X}) = \sum_i p_i log_2 \frac{1}{p_i}$$

So if were to minimize the number of bits and maximize the information you're able to store, you'd choose $log_2 \frac{1}{p_i}$ bits for each symbol, as it's the definition of the *information* of that symbol.

Comment: What is Shannon information?(I've googled it and the only results that I find are related to information theory)